# If $A$ is a singular square matrix, then $Ax = b \neq \vec{0}$ has $0$ or many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I was reading this pdf:

> https://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math3600/lecture10.pdf

and it tells you that

> if $A$ is a singular square matrix, then $Ax = b \neq \vec{0}$ has $0$ or many solutions.

My question is: when does it have $0$ and when it has many solutions? In other words, how does $b$ influence the number of solutions for this linear system of equations in this case?

Note, I'm not asking why such a system of equations doesn't have a unique solution.

Comment: If $b\in \mathcal R(A)$, then the equation has infinitely many solution, else there's no solution.

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean with $b$ influencing the number of solutions? Can you give an example of an answer you might expect (even if it is wrong)?

Comment: @GitGud I suppose that he was referring to the situation where $b$ is (or isn't) in the range of $A$, a singular matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The system of equation  $Ax=b$ has solutions if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(Ab)$ (the augmented matrix).

If so, the set of solutions is an affine subspace  with codimension $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$.